# Derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector.

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am unsure if the matrix derivation rules provided in the text are applicable to this situation:

As part of a larger problem, I need to evaluate:

$$\frac{d}{dB}AB^T$$

where $B^T$ is the transpose of $B$.

$A_{(N,1)}$ and $B_{(3x1)}$ are matrices.

The text states:

$$\frac{df}{dW}W^TX=X$$

$$\frac{df}{dW}X^TW=X$$

But my problem seems to follow the format:

$$\frac{df}{dW}XW^T$$

Can I assume one of the cases listed in the text? Or maybe there is a more intuitive way to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Wikipedia article about differentiating with respect to a vector / matrix?

Comment: The expression you are trying to evaluate will lead to a third order tensor. It may not be even possible to evaluate the expression using usual matrix vector operations. Please use tensor analysis to do it.